# OS X app works in 10.10 and not 10.9.5

Tags: xcode, macos

I have developed an OS X app using Xcode 6 on OS X 10.10.4.  The app runs great in 10.10.4.  When I copy and attempt to run in OS X 10.9.5, the app icon appears in the dock but the main window does not show.  In addition, only the first menu item is displayed.  Activity Monitor shows it running but idle at 0% CPU.  There is nothing on the system log and no output written from my app.  The app does not crash but sits idle in the dock.

The app settings use OS X 10.8 as the minimum target.

I have not installed Xcode and tried to rebuild as the project file is for Xcode 6, and I would have to downgrade to Xcode 5.x on OS X 10.9.5.

Thoughts on how to solve this?  Is there a tool to diagnose this?

Comment: Setting the minimum target doesn't mean you didn't use API's available on 10.10+

Comment: I was careful not to use any APIs that did not support 10.8.  If what you mention were the case, I would expect an alert stating the app would not work.  Or am I wrong about this?

Comment: Open Console.app, open your app, read the logs. There's good chances it will complain about the problem there.

Comment: @dmetzler: Is your application using `storyboards` or `nibs/xibs`?

Comment: storyboards.  yes - that was it!  I had mistakenly thought storyboards were introduced before 101.0, but that is not the case.  reverted to xibs and the app runs in 10.8/10.9.